# Is anyone using JMagick on Windows

Tags: image-manipulation, jmagick

For deploy I'll be using Linux, but dev is done on Windows.  Has anyone used it lately on Windows?  Have you had any problems?

Do you have an updated Makefile for VC++ that you can share?  It seems the directory structure for the latest Magick is quite different that what the old makefile I found in jmagick is expecting.

The plot thickens.  In my attempts to compile the c sources, it is looking for files such as magick_ImageInfo.h that don't exist in the source tree.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it's been a while since you posted, so I'm guessing that you've already solved your problem. I'm posting this anyway, maybe it'll help others.

It's quite easy to use JMagick on Windows. Their wiki has [some information](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jmagick/index.php?title=Installing_JMagick) regarding this. In short, you need to have [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed, `jmagick.dll` somewhere on the OS `%PATH%` and `jmagick.jar` in your classpath.

You can download all these binaries from the Jmagick [download site](http://downloads.jmagick.org/6.3.9/).